# How to upload dynamic data from a store that comes from a json

Tags: extjs

I would like to upload data from a store that has the following characteristics:

1. has two fields 'YEAR' and 'SALES'
2. a proxy that via url connects to a json
3. the data is set inline with the data property

Here is the model code:

```
Ext.define('DashboardClienti.model.ChartFatturato', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    alias: 'model.chartfatturato',
    

    identifier: 'negative',


    fields: [
    {
        name: 'ANNO_0',
        type: 'int'
    },{
        name: 'ANNO_1',
        type: 'int'
    },{
        name: 'ANNO_2',
        type: 'int'
    },{
        name: 'FATTURATO_TOT_ANNO_0',
        type: 'float'
    },{
        name: 'FATTURATO_TOT_ANNO_1',
        type: 'float'
    },{
        name: 'FATTURATO_TOT_ANNO_2',
        type: 'float'
    }],
    
 

});
```

Here is the store code:

```
Ext.define('DashboardClienti.store.ChartFatturato', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.chartfatturato',
    storeId: 'chartfatturatoStore',

    model: 'DashboardClienti.model.ChartFatturato',


   
    
        fields: ['ANNO','FATTURATO'],


    data: [
        { ANNO: 'ANNO_0',  FATTURATO: 'FATTURATO_TOT_ANNO_0' },
        { ANNO: 'ANNO_1',  FATTURATO: 'FATTURATO_TOT_ANNO_0' },
        { ANNO: 'ANNO_2',  FATTURATO: 'FATTURATO_TOT_ANNO_0' }
    
    ],
    


    
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',

        url : AppConstants.UrlCustomersDetail,
        method : 'GET',

        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }, 
        /*extraParams: {
            format: 'json'
        } 
        */   
    }
    
    
});
```

From the proxy that takes data from a json I get this data:

```
ANNO_0: 2021
ANNO_1: 2020
ANNO_2: 2019
CAP: "32021"
CITTA: "AGORDO"
CODICE: "1010"
CODICE_FISCALE: "0000000000"
EMAIL: "johndoe@gmail.com"
FATTURATO_PER_ANNO_0: 0
FATTURATO_PER_ANNO_1: 1321.84
FATTURATO_PER_ANNO_2: 3058.25
FATTURATO_TOT_ANNO_0: 0
FATTURATO_TOT_ANNO_1: 3426.71
FATTURATO_TOT_ANNO_2: 5274.32
FRAZIONE: ""
ID: 40832
ID_1: 7594
ID_2: 0
ID_AGENTE: 0
ID_CAPOAREA: 0
ID_CLIENTE: 40832
ID_CLIENTE_1: 0
ID_DITTA: 1
INDIRIZZO: "PIAZZA LIBERTÀ, 17-18"
NAZIONE: "IT"
PARTITA_IVA: "000000000"
PERIODO_AL: "2021-06-30T00:00:00.000Z"
PERSONA_RIFERIMENTO_1: ""
PERSONA_RIFERIMENTO_2: ""
.....
```

I would like to know how to load the data from the proxy in the DATA property of the store because the YEAR AND SALES fields are not filled in with the proxy values.

Comment: You should delete the `data` property for starter, and add the `autoLoad` property into the Store.

Comment: First of all, do you wanna upload (send the data to a server) or do you wanna load data from a server into a store? As far as i understand it you wanna load the data from the last code snippet into a store, using a proxy? If its right, i would use a simple ajax request, get the data, and then transform it into an array and load / add it to a store. Or better, if possible to the conversion within the backend. Out of the box the proxy wont create many records from one load - in order to do this you would need to intercept the store load and transform it there.

Comment: did you try: store.loadRawData(data)